# Best way to alter jquery version in Django admin

Tags: jquery, django, django-admin

What is the best way to load jQuery on all Django admin pages. I would like to load it from Google CDN, at the moment I have to remember to load it on all my admin pages separatelly.

Answer (score 5):

Django comes with jQuery by default. If you just need jQuery and don't mind using the same version Django uses (a little outdated), you can just wrap your code with:

```
(function($){
    // your code, use `$` as normal
})(django.jQuery);
```

However, if you want a newer version of jQuery, it is *not* recommended to actually change the version of jQuery Django uses. Thankfully, since Django namespaces its version of jQuery by default (as `django.jQuery`), you can load your own version as normal without causing any conflicts.

Create a file at `<project_root>/templates/admin/base_site.html`. Copy and paste the code from [the default `base_site.html`](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.3.1/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base_site.html) (minimal amount of code here, so won't affect upgrades), and add the following block:

```
{% block extrahead %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Of course, you can change that to any version of jQuery you want.

Comment: Actually this is what I've done, but it seems it loads django jQuery as well... I use admin_tools, which needs jQuery.

Comment: Huh? Of course it still loads Django's jQuery as well. That's the point. Django needs its version of jQuery. There's nothing you can do about that. You can either use it or load your own jQuery *in addition* to it.

Comment: Yeap, but this means conflicts, "hackish" "noConflict" lines and doubling script that browser needs to load...

Comment: Well, first it certainly doesn't mean conflicts and "hackish noConflict" lines. Django's jQuery is already namespaced, so you don't have to do anything special at all with the second version you load. You can even use the `$` if you want. Second, doubling the script load sucks, yes, but we're talking 16k that's only served to the few people that actually use your admin. It's really nothing. Finally, and most importantly, you have *no choice*. You can't replace Django's version of jQuery, so you either have to use its version or add your own additional version. Period.

Comment: Chris is correct in that the proper way is to add your own jQuery object in addition to django.jQuery. But, if you really want to replace django.jQuery you can create your own AdminSite class and override the media dynamic property, and create a namespace for django.jQuery that points to your newer version. This is not advisable, however, as django admin was written to be compatible with a specific version of jquery.

Answer (score 0):

From here - http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter06/

> The admin site finds the “Django administration” header by looking for
>   the template admin/base_site.html. By default, this template lives in
>   the Django admin template directory, django/contrib/admin/templates,
>   which you can find by looking in your Python site-packages directory,
>   or wherever Django was installed. To customize this base_site.html
>   template, copy that template into an admin subdirectory of whichever
>   directory you’re using in TEMPLATE_DIRS. For example, if your
>   TEMPLATE_DIRS includes "/home/mytemplates", then copy
>   django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base_site.html to
>   /home/mytemplates/admin/base_site.html. Don’t forget that admin
>   subdirectory. 3
>
> Then, just edit the new admin/base_site.html file to replace the
>   generic Django text with your own site’s name as you see fit.

So just add/edit the jquery include in this custiomised file.

Hope that helps...

Comment: Yeap, this was my first thought, but I need to copy this file - what if Django version changes?