# Does Django have jQuery built-in?

Tags: jquery, django

Is it need to add jQuery to every project I create or does the latest Django version (1.5.1) has it built-in? So I can import it from the framework directly for use? My question comes from after reading this [**part**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#jquery) in the documentation.
And then I found this [**pyip-package**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-jquery/1.9.1) which install jquery so I can add it into `INSTALLED_APPS` list in settings.py.

My question is if I need to install something extra, or does Django have already so I can add jQuery without?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes and no.

Django 1.5's `django.contrib.admin` does have jQuery v1.4.2 packaged up for all Admin features (date pickers etc)

If you are happy with v1.4.2 then you can include it like so:

```
{% load static %}
<script src="{% static 'admin/js/jquery.js' %}"></script>
```

However your best bet is probably to include it yourself.

There are various PyPI packages that have packed jQuery up for you if you want to use them (personally I find they don't contain the latest versions)

My set up uses a CDN with local backup and looks like so:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src={% static "myapp/js/vendor/jquery-2.0.0.min.js" %}><\/script>')</script>
```

CDNs have various advantages including (no particular order):

1. Probably faster than your hosting
2. The User might already have it cached from another site
3. Less traffic for your hosting

Comment: For more information on `Django.jQuery` vs custom `jQuery` , see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9136234/11875147).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it is called 'django.jQuery'!

In [admin\change_list.html](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list.html) at line 27:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function($) {
        $("tr input.action-select").actions();
    });
})(django.jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, Django does not have jQuery included.

In my opinion, the easiest way to install jQuery is to add this line

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to the `<head/>` of your `base.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```